# JS - Initializing DOM elements with simple .init(); method?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a bunch of reusable dropdown lists, that all behave the same. When the page loads, they are already in the DOM:

```
<body>

    <div class="dd-list" id="myDD1">
        ... stuff
    </div>

    <div class="dd-list" id="myDD2">
        ... stuff
    </div>

</body>
```

But the behaviour is not currently attached to each element. They just sit there and do nothing.

*Using Pure JS*, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.dd-list');

lists.forEach(function(list, index) {
    list.init();
});
```

But I'm unsure how to write the method `init()` so that it can act on each `list` with simple dot notation. I don't need to store the lists (or references to the lists) in memory, and this is exclusively to attach the behaviour to them.

I had something like:

```
// List behaviour 

(function(window) {

    function DDList(el) {
        var self = this;

        self._init(el);
    }

    DDList.prototype._init = function(el) {
        self.menu = el;
        self.list = self.menu.querySelector('ul');

        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log(self.list);    // Just for testing
        });
    }   

    ... and other methods       

    window.DDList = DDList;

})(window);


// Find the lists, initialize them

(function() {
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.dd-list');

    lists.forEach(function(list, index) {
        new DDList(list);
    });
})();
```

But after initializing them both, clicking on either of the lists printed the list items from the *second* list only. I can print information as each is initializing, and the both do initialize separately, but it seems that somehow the second initialization overrides the first.

Like I mentioned, I don't need (or want) to store references to anything. That's why I chose to do `new DDList(list);`, opposed to `var list1 = new DDList(list);`

I'm looking for something simple, but a little more elegant and reusable than just putting the `addEventListener` within the `forEach`.

Comment: in your _init() method you are using `self` without defining it, this means it is going to be the global `self` as in `window` and not the instance reference of `self` you made in the constructor. So no matter the instance you use you are using the same global, and therefore the same `.menu` and `.list`

Comment: Yup. Throw that into an answer, and the glory is all yours. Just a lazy miss on my part.